# How to use System.lineSeparator() as a constant in Java tests

Tags: java, testng

I am trying to use `System.lineSeparator()` in a Java testng test case to build the `expectedExceptionsMessageRegExp` as below.

```java
@Test(description = "When path parameter has given unmatch data type in ballerina",
            expectedExceptions = BallerinaOpenApiException.class,
            expectedExceptionsMessageRegExp = "File has errors: " + System.lineSeparator() + "Semicolon is missing at line 45")
public void testMissionSemicolon() throws IOException, BallerinaOpenApiException {
  // test implementation
}
```

I am getting below error at `expectedExceptionsMessageRegExp`.

```
Attribute value must be constant
```

What is the reason for this error? How can I achieve my purpose ?

Comment: Since this is system dependent, it would not make sense to make it a constant.

Answer (score 9):

There is a distinction between a compile-time constant and a run-time constant.  Annotation values must be compile-time constants.

A compile-time constant is a value known at compile time, such as

```
static final int ZERO = 0;
```

A runtime constant is a value known to not change, but whose value is not known at compile time:

```
static final int RANDOM = random.nextInt();
```

Annotation values must be compile-time constants.

Since the value of `lineSeparator()` changes based on what OS you are running on, it cannot be a compile-time constant.

Answer (score 1):

If you receive that error from an other platform,  the line separator might be different. `System.lineSeparator` differs per platform.

Solution: Use `\\R` which is the regexp for any newline. And RegExp it is!

```
expectedExceptionsMessageRegExp = "File has errors: \\RSemicolon is missing at line 45")
```

Compiled Annotations are stored with the code, and require for this compile time constants. Evaluations are only done in annotations processing code.
`"abc" + "def"` would compile to `"abcdef"`, but not with `System.lineSeparator`.